# How to create a new column on an existing Dataframe based on values of another Dataframe both of which are of different length

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new column on an existing dataframe based on values of another dataframe.

```
# Define a dataframe containing 2 columns Date-Year and Date-Qtr
data1 = {'Date-Year': [2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017], 
        'Date-Qtr': ['2015Q1', '2015Q2', '2015Q3', '2015Q4', '2016Q1', '2016Q2', '2016Q3', '2016Q4', '2017Q1', '2017Q2']} 

dfx = pd.DataFrame(data1)

# Define another dataframe containing 2 columns Date-Year and Interest Rate
data2 = {'Date-Year': [2000, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021], 
        'Interest Rate': [0.00, 8.20, 8.20, 7.75, 7.50, 7.50, 6.50, 6.50]} 

dfy = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# Add 1 more column to the first dataframe
dfx['Int-rate'] = float(0)
```

Output for dfx

```
   Date-Year Date-Qtr  Int-rate
0       2015   2015Q1       0.0
1       2015   2015Q2       0.0
2       2015   2015Q3       0.0
3       2015   2015Q4       0.0
4       2016   2016Q1       0.0
5       2016   2016Q2       0.0
6       2016   2016Q3       0.0
7       2016   2016Q4       0.0
8       2017   2017Q1       0.0
9       2017   2017Q2       0.0
```

Output for dfy

```
Date-Year  Interest Rate
0       2000           0.00
1       2015           8.20
2       2016           8.20
3       2017           7.75
4       2018           7.50
5       2019           7.50
6       2020           6.50
7       2021           6.50
```

Now I need to update the column 'Int-rate' of dfx by picking up the value for 'Interest Rate' from dfy for its corresponding year which I am achieving through 2 FOR loops

```
#Check the year from dfx - goto dfy - check the interest rate from dfy for that year and modify Int-rate of dfx with this value
for i in range (len(dfx['Date-Year'])):
    for j in range (len(dfy['Date-Year'])):
        if (dfx['Date-Year'][i] == dfy['Date-Year'][j]):
            dfx['Int-rate'][i] = dfy['Interest Rate'][j]
```

and I get the desired output

```
  Date-Year Date-Qtr  Int-rate
0       2015   2015Q1      8.20
1       2015   2015Q2      8.20
2       2015   2015Q3      8.20
3       2015   2015Q4      8.20
4       2016   2016Q1      8.20
5       2016   2016Q2      8.20
6       2016   2016Q3      8.20
7       2016   2016Q4      8.20
8       2017   2017Q1      7.75
9       2017   2017Q2      7.75
```

**Is there a way I can achieve the same output**

1. without declaring `dfx['Int-rate'] = float(0)`. I get a `KeyError: 'Int-rate'`if I don't declare this
2. not very happy with the 2 FOR loops. Is it possible to get it done in a better way (like using map or merge or joins)

I have tried looking through other posts and the best one I found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36413993/replace-column-values-in-one-dataframe-by-values-of-another-dataframe), tried using map but I could not do it. Any help will be appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with a dictionary:

```
dfx['Int-Rate'] = dfx['Date-Year'].replace(dict(dfy.to_numpy()))
print(dfx)
```

**Output**

```
   Date-Year Date-Qtr  Int-Rate
0       2015   2015Q1      8.20
1       2015   2015Q2      8.20
2       2015   2015Q3      8.20
3       2015   2015Q4      8.20
4       2016   2016Q1      8.20
5       2016   2016Q2      8.20
6       2016   2016Q3      8.20
7       2016   2016Q4      8.20
8       2017   2017Q1      7.75
9       2017   2017Q2      7.75
```

Or with a Series as an alternative:

```
dfx['Int-Rate'] = dfx['Date-Year'].replace(dfy.set_index('Date-Year').squeeze())
```

Comment: Thanks Dani, both options works like a charm. I need to explore a bit more both these areas

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
In [4448]: df = dfx.merge(dfy).rename(columns={'Interest Rate':'Int-rate'})

In [4449]: df
Out[4449]: 
   Date-Year Date-Qtr  Int-rate
0       2015   2015Q1      8.20
1       2015   2015Q2      8.20
2       2015   2015Q3      8.20
3       2015   2015Q4      8.20
4       2016   2016Q1      8.20
5       2016   2016Q2      8.20
6       2016   2016Q3      8.20
7       2016   2016Q4      8.20
8       2017   2017Q1      7.75
9       2017   2017Q2      7.75
```

Comment: @JaideepBanerjee Did my answer not work for you?

Comment: Yes Mayank, this too works. thx