# Replace all values of a column in dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new using dataframes and I don't know how to do this.

I have this dataframe (sample):

```
     Type                                    Count
0    http://dbpedia.org/resource/Album       21
1    http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Book     4
2    http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Person   7
3    http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Film     4
```

I want to replace ALL the values of `Type` column, result will be like this (sample):

```
    Type      Count
0   Album     21
1   Book      4
2   Person    7
3   Film      4
```

Hope you can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `extract` the ending word (`\w*$`) in each string:

```
df['Type'] = df.Type.str.extract('(\w*)$')
df

     Type  Count
0   Album     21
1    Book      4
2  Person      7
3    Film      4
```

Or `split` and then take the last element:

```
df['Type'] = df.Type.str.split('/').str[-1]
df

     Type  Count
0   Album     21
1    Book      4
2  Person      7
3    Film      4
```

Comment: Not that I'm the expert. But wouldn't a better method be to replace with a matching dataframe like a vlookup ? 2 seperate corresponding matching lists, no matter the content, so the solution isn't reliant on a textual manipulation. I'm out now otherwise I would try that.

Comment: @DavidWooley-AST I think you are talking about excel ? This is a question for pandas.

Comment: No, I was talking more about something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846060/how-to-replace-an-entire-column-on-pandas-dataframe) but using excel language to explain my idea. Or something like df['Group'] = df['Type'].map(df1.set_index('Type')['Name']) from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36413993/replace-column-values-in-one-dataframe-by-values-of-another-dataframe)